# accessing the data inside array-key-array-objects

Tags: php

**This is the data inside a variable named $data and i printed it using print_r().**

```
Array
(
[user_id] => 6
[car_id] => 9
[pickup_name] => only me
[snooze] => 15
[pickup_loc] => pickup location
[drop_loc] => drop location
[note] => see you soon
[schedule] => [ {
"id": "1",
"car_name": "Mercedes-Benz C-Class",
"price": "200",
"status": "0",
"cr_dt": "2019-07-25 18:29:42",
"up_dt": "2019-07-26 11:20:36"
},
{
"id": "2",
"car_name": "Mercedes-Benz C-Class",
"price": "300",
"status": "0",
"cr_dt": "2019-07-25 18:29:42",
"up_dt": "2019-07-26 11:20:36"
} ]
[id] => 16
)
```

I want to access the data inside ['schedule'] in my foreach loop.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: json_decode( $data['schedule], true)

Comment: will you plese give me a code with foreach loop as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_decode( $data['schedule])` directly. Otherwise you can use a variable like:

```
$jsarray = json_decode( $data['schedule])
```

Then you can access the data.

Comment: i am trying this and it is still throwing error.$sch = json_decode( $data['schedule'], true);

        if(isset($data['schedule']))
        {

        foreach($sch as $sc)
        {
            print_r($sc->id);
        }
        
        }

Comment: watch what the output comes from this, $jsarray = json_decode( $data['schedule]); print_r($jsarray);exit;

Comment: @jarvis `$sc['id']`